# Bootstrap Toggle attribute for audio

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to make an attribute with toggle.

This is my code:

**Javascript :**

```
myfunc(mute){
    var className=a.getAttribute("class")
    if(className=="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"){
        a.className="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"
    }
    else{
        a.className="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"
    }
```

**HTML :**

```
<li><a onclick="myfunc(mute)" href="#" id="mute" style="font-size:20px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"> </a></li>
```

Now, what I want to do?

First, music plays, but nobody likes it, and If person clicks on attribute i want to change class to: `glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off`. So, second click I want to be `glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up`. However, you will understand. A mute button.

Comment: '      <li><a onclick="myfunc(mute)" href="#" id="mute" style="font-size:20px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"> </a></li>' HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Oh, resolved!

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.toggleAudio',function(){
    $(this).children().toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up");
});
```